# Is it better to delete or to edit a downvoted answered question?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, etiquette, post-ban, self-delete

I have [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18153307/2628257) that shows poor research. Due to this and my first steps at Stack Overflow I got banned from asking questions. Ever since I'm trying to earn my way back to asking.

Recently, I tried editing this question, which was already properly answered. While researching about being unbanned I read that editing existing question was necessary. When doing so, I accidentally typed a shortcut that automatically saved my edit, which was incomplete. Hence getting me an extra negative point.

Should I delete it? I could try and edit it again, but now that I solved that question it's a bit odd to try and ask it again.

Comment: A single question will not get you question banned.

Comment: Deletion works toward the ban.

Comment: OFF: I vote on your downvoted question on SO. Seems useful for me. Don't be disencouraged by 2 single downvotes!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do not delete the post.

If you delete the post, how will you improve it?

You say you saved an edit by mistake - what stopped you from correcting it and saving the better version? Go do that now.

You say the issue was solved by an answer? Great. But you can still improve the question - make it better. It just might attract enough upvotes to get you out of the ban.

The question ban doesn't stop you from editing your existing questions. If you can find any of your deleted questions, you can undelete them and improve them as well.

Comment: Thanks, will do that with the deleted ones. I did edit it again to improve it. I'll try and make it even more ellaborated.

Comment: @chuckleplant - Just be careful that you don't edit it so much that the answer/s given is/are no longer valid/correct.

Comment: btw, what if the deleted questions themselves show little research effort? For example something that a google search would solve, wouldn't that give me more downvotes even if I edit them to perfection?

Comment: @chuckleplant - Frankly, if you think the deleted question doesn't belong on [so], it is better to leave it deleted (otherwise, it may very well attract more downvotes and dig you deeper into the question ban).

Comment: Related topic, what about comments? Deleting them works the same way as questions? Or can I freely delete them?

Comment: @chuckleplant You can freely delete comments.