# Commenting to recommend deletion

Tags: discussion, comments, off-topic, ethics

So I just saw a question that asked for a recommendation. These questions are almost always closed because they require opinions. Is it a good idea to comment and tell the OP they may want to delete it before it gets downvoted as an opinion based question?

Comment: Chances are they will delete it after their question begins receiving downvotes to save their reputation.

Comment: Just curious, since you ask this you obviously got account with 50+ rep on SO, why are you using different acount here on Meta? Are we *that* scary?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @inquisitiveidiot not sure how you managed that; if you're using the same OpenID provider they should be automatically associated. Anyway, follow [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) to see how to merge your accounts.

Comment: @inquisitiveidiot nope, still can't see your Stack Overflow account associated. Anyway, get ready for a nice +100 bonus when it does get associated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I do when my question is getting downvotes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200201/what-should-i-do-when-my-question-is-getting-downvotes)

Comment: see also: [Is it better to delete or to edit a downvoted answered question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199446/is-it-better-to-delete-or-to-edit-a-downvoted-answered-question)

Comment: @gnat both fair points but I was asking specifically about commenting to tell someone to delete his or her question. The context may help. At the time I also thought I didn't have enough rep to flag. for context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429376/recommendation-for-good-resource-about-computer-science-related-research-and-inv

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always explain to the OP that the post is not suitable and explain why (links to related questions/blog posts are always a bonus on these).

With luck, the OP will delete the post themselves, saving the community some time and effort.

If the post gets deleted, the reputation lost gets refunded, so that's not a real consideration here.

In short - it doesn't hurt, but you shouldn't stop with just a comment. Flagging the post as off-topic is the most correct thing to do.

Comment: I think you forgot to mention that deletions pave a road to question ban

Comment: @gnat - Bad questions pave the road to question bans...

Comment: deleting instead of editing to improve makes this road a speedway, doesn't it

Comment: @gnat - It certainly doesn't help, but more because deleted questions are not improved and cannot get upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

I believe most important is to flag the question as off-topic, but also leaving a comment explaining why it is off-topic on Stack Overflow can be useful and kind, especially to help new users quickly understand how the community works.

Others might disagree about your comment, though.

Answer (score 2):

I would not rely on the user in such cases. What if the user doesn't delete his question? What if he already has deleted a few questions and deleting that one more will get him banned?

The right thing to do is to flag it.

The kind thing to do is to leave an advisory comment.